# Reinstalling a fresh Windows 7 on a SSD while its original HDD version was upgraded to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, reinstall

Many posts around that subject, but this case is a bit specific (I think) since it's *not* about a migration *nor* a cloning.

- Initially Windows 7 on a `500GB HDD` (OEM)
- then upgrade to Windows 10 (offered by Microsoft)

Now we have a brand new `550GB SSD` and would like to install a *fresh* Windows  on it (and get rid of the old one on the HDD).

- Do we have to install the initial (Win 7) or the upgraded (Win 10) on the SSD?
- What happens with the license, will Microsoft accept the license "transfer" automatically?

We'd prefer to install Windows 7, unless 10 is mandatory (or recommended).

Edit

Actually we'll go for win 10 since we need to switch languages after the install (thanks @Ramhound). Thus the question is back to the classical Win 10 reinstall, and is definitely a dupe . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upgraded to Windows 10 future Windows 10 installations will accept just the motherboard serial being the same. It's also possible CPU and HDD serials would be used.

However when reinstalling Windows 7 the same rules apply that did before. You'll need a key unless its SLP. Windows 7 in my experience is more touchy when changing the storage device however this is still legal for you to do so if it fails you should be able to call to activate.

Comment: Windows 7 devices do not have the license key store in the ACPI table like Windows 8+ device.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to but SLP applies to Windows 7 even Windows XP.